# How to set a field value only when document modified?

Tags: mongodb

I'm updating many documents using a bulk operation, but I only want to bump the timestamp of documents that are changed by the new values.

Currently my bulk operation looks something like this:

```
var updates = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
// ...
updates.find( someQuery ).update( { 
    $set: someValues,
    $currentDate: { modified:true }
} );
updates.execute();
```

Even if `someValues` doesn't modify any fields, the `modified` field gets set. Is there a way to provide a list of additional updates to be performed only when the original update results in a change?

I'm running MongoDB 2.6

I want to avoid negating all the object values in the query one by one.